# Htaccess: Hide php file behind nice seo friendly url

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

So I have "nice" urls:

```
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ page.php?data=$1 [L]
```

The problem is that `page.php` is accessible so `site.com/page.php?data=xxx` will show duplicate content of `site.com/xxx/`

I want to prevent that, but if I do any `Redirect` or `RewriteRule` even before the nice url `RewriteRule` it affects/makes the file inaccessible even behind the nice url.

Is there any way?

I can change `page.php` to a rare filename, and in case its discovered and published, add html `canonical urls`, but I would like to do it right.

Comment: try looking into php routing systems, or php frameworks in general, like laravel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add this before your first `RewriteCond`:

```
# external redirect from actual URL to pretty one
RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/+page\.php\?data=([^\s&]+) [NC]
RewriteRule ^ /%1/? [R=301,L,NE]
```

Comment: Well I don't want to redirect this to the nice url, I wanted to "hide" these files, plus I have some different nice urls and it will be an unnecessary large file.

After fighting a bit I got this working:

`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^.*\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ 404.html [R=302,L]`

But I have a very little problem, it maintains any GET data, all after ?. There is not much problem, but how can I make it to go to a clean 404.hml url?

Comment: Got it. I had difficulties because I was working on a subfolder and I didn’t know where to add it.
`RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} \s/page\.php [NC]
RewriteRule ^ 404.html? [R=302,L]`

Comment: @Vixxs Don't externally redirect to a 404, rewrite internally and set the status header in the 404 file.